# Zookeeper best practice - using only SSD disks

Tags: redhat, hard-drive, ssd, hadoop, zookeeper

we have HDP clusters version 2.6.0 / 2.6.1 ( hortonworks ) , and maybe in the future the version 3.0

I searched a lot in HORTONWORKS documentation , but not found the details about using SSD disks for zookeeper

but on confluent , we can see that they fully recommended that zookeeper servers must works with SSD

Reference: https://docs.confluent.io/current/zookeeper/deployment.html

Disk performance is vital to maintaining a healthy Zookeeper cluster. Solid state drives (SSD) are highly recommended as Zookeeper must have low latency disk writes in order to perform optimally. Each request to Zookeeper must be committed to to disk on each server in the quorum before the result is available for read. A dedicated SSD of at least 64 GB in size on each Zookeeper server is recommended for a production deployment. You can use autopurge.purgeInterval and autopurge.snapRetainCount to automatically cleanup Zookeeper data and lower maintenance overhead.

so We want to know if we need to replace our disks with SSD disks ( only for the zookeeper )

any other opinions about this ?

dose zookeeper server must use - SSD disks ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not mendetory to use SSD I think only reason to suggest SSD is depend on type of application you are going to use. If you have transaction based applications and doing interaction with zookeeper on every transactions it's good to have ssd, I used zookeeper for Kafka, Hadoop but never used ssd only for zookeeper.
Hope this will help.